# Postgres Function returns too many columns

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am trying to create a function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_post(integer) RETURNS SETOF post AS $$
select *, lag(id) over (order by id) as prev_id, lead(id) over (order by id) as next_id
from post
where id=$1 limit 1;
$$ language SQL;
```

but it gives me error like.

```
Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  return type mismatch in function declared to return post
DETAIL:  Final statement returns too many columns.
```

I know the error is due to the `prev_id` and `next_id` in the select. But not sure how I can include the `next_id` and `prev_id` on the return.

you can use this sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6e6dd6/4

EDIT:
it gives me the same error after converting the query using subquery.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_post(integer) RETURNS SETOF post AS $$
select 
    p.*,
    (select id from post where id>p.id ORDER BY id asc LIMIT 1) as next_id, 
    (select id from post where id<p.id ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 1) as prev_id
from post p
where id=$1 limit 1;
$$ language SQL;
```

Comment: Even if this worked, it would not do what you want.  The `WHERE` clause filters before the `LEAD()` and `LAG()` so those results will be `NULL`.  You need to use a subquery or CTE.  Well, I can actually think of a way around that, but it is quite expensive.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, yeah, you are right, it returns NULL using the where clause. any workaround ?

Comment: . . I already explained in the answer to your previous question that you simply use a subquery (or CTE if you prefer).

Comment: @GordonLinoff, yes, using the subquery also I am receiving same error. see my edit.

Comment: . . I am not recommending a UDF for this purpose.  Just use a subquery in your query.

Comment: Your UDF does not work as the return type is said to be ````SETOF post``, but in reality you are not returning ```post.*```, but you add additional columns. This is why the error comes up. You can try ```SETOF RECORD``` or ```RETURNS TABLE(...)```. See the docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html